# Whats wrong with the selection sort?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, selection-sort

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Patient
{
int priority;
char name[30];
char email[20];
char phone[10];
};

void SortPatient(Patient patient[], int numpatient)
{
for(int i = 0;i < numpatient - 1; ++i)
{
    int min = i;
    for(int j = i + 1;j < numpatient; ++j)
    {
```

it gives me an error at this if condition([Error] request for member 'compare' in '(patient + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 64ull)))->Patient::priority', which is of non-class type 'int'

```
     if( patient[i].priority.compare(patient[j].priority) < 0 )
     {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    if( min != i )
    {
        Patient temp = patient[i];
        patient[i]       = patient[min];
        patient[min]     = temp;
    }
}
}
int main(){

Patient ds;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout<<"Patient #"<<i<<": "<<endl;
    cout<<"Priority: ";
    cin>> ds[i].priority;
    cout<<endl<<"Name: ";
    cin.get(ds[i].name,30);
    cout<<endl<<"Email: ";
    cin.get(ds[i].email,20);
    cout<<endl<<"Phone: "<<endl;
    cin.get(ds[i].phone,10);
}
```

Comment: what isnt clear about the error message? `patient[i].priority` is an `int` and has no methods. What `compare` do you want to call?

Comment: Seems like you mixed up languages? Did you mean `patient[i].priority < patient[j].priority`?

Comment: btw do yourself a favor and use `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: @churill now its ok thanks, but can you check my input method for sturct patient its it correct

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have not used c++ for long time now.